# Rails migration - changing the attribute name of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration, rails-migrations

In my Rails model for `Comment`, I have attributes`message`, `date` attributes along `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes automatically provided by `ActiveRecord::Migration` via `t.timestamps`.

Currently the date attribute has values in db ( postgresql ) for `comments` table. I want to remove the `date` attribute in `Comment` model and while doing this want to update the `comments` db table values for `created_at` attribute with value in `date` attribute.

How do I go about this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `created_at` should have an accurate datetime of when the record was created. I would just remove the superfluous `date` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the rails code inside the migration file as below to update the column value.

Assuming datatype of column `date` is `timestamp`.

```
class RemoveDateFromComment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Comment.all.each do |comment|
      comment.update(created_at: comment.date)
    end

    remove_column :comments, :date, :timestamp
  end

  def down
    add_column :comments, :date, :timestamp

    Comment.all.each do |comment|
      comment.update(date: comment.created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: good - this works for most part , except the fact that is there a way to revert to existing values in `created_at` column before applying the migration ?

Comment: What do you mean by revert to existing values in `created_at` column before applying the migration ? Sorry, I can't understand.

Comment: `created_at` had some values for each comment before we applied the `up` migration. Is there there a way to get those values back if we do the `down` migration ?

Comment: No, it's not possible.